# php-win.exe application error wampserver 2.5

Tags: php

the application unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). click OK to close the application

installed mvscr110.dll file, vc++ 2012 redistributable package but nothing helped

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was caused by uninstalling some Visual C++ libraries that shouldn't have been uninstalled, namely the 2012 editions.

I corrected this by re-installing the [Visual C++ 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) and that worked. Remember to download the correct version depending what platform PHP you're running (x86 or x64).